# Airflow DAG for detecting file drop in GCP bucket not working

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am attempting to trigger a dummy process from dropping a file in a bucket. I am monitoring this bucket using the GoogleCloudStorageObjectSensor.

I run the DAG manually and the GoogleCloudStorageObjectSensor object runs successfully. I drop a file in the bucket and there is never a reaction to this event.

The logs for the DAG never seem to throw an error and appear as if it is being monitored but the dummy process is never triggered. I have set the DAG to run in debug mode, but the logs never changed.

The code for the dag is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd 

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.contrib.sensors.gcs_sensor import GoogleCloudStorageObjectSensor

BUCKET_TO_MONITOR = 'landing-wba-dev'

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['XXX.XXX@XXX.XXX'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 20,
    'retry_delay': 300,
}

# Create the DAG instance
dag = DAG(
    'gcs_bucket_monitoring_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Monitor GCS bucket and trigger DAG on file arrival',
    schedule_interval=None, 
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1), # required
)

# # Define the GCS Sensor
gcs_sensor = GoogleCloudStorageObjectSensor(
    task_id='gcs_sensor',
    bucket=BUCKET_TO_MONITOR,
    object='*',  # Use a wildcard to match any object in the bucket
    mode='poke',  # Use 'poke' mode to actively poll for the object
    poke_interval=10,  # Poll every 10 seconds
    timeout=7200,  # Timeout after 1 hours
    dag=dag,
)

# Define a DummyOperator to trigger the processing task
dummy_processing = DummyOperator(
    task_id='trigger_processing',
    dag=dag,
)

# Set up task dependencies
gcs_sensor >> dummy_processing
```

The log from Airflow shows the following:

```
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=Airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=gcs_bucket_monitoring_dag
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=gcs_sensor
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-09-12T13:06:37.956825+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2023-09-12T13:06:37.956825+00:00
[2023-09-12, 13:06:44 UTC] {gcs.py:93} INFO - Sensor checks existence of : landing-wba-dev, *
[2023-09-12, 13:06:44 UTC] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 'google_cloud_default' for task execution.
[2023-09-12, 13:06:44 UTC] {credentials_provider.py:354} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no explicit credentials are provided.
[2023-09-12, 13:07:44 UTC] {gcs.py:93} INFO - Sensor checks existence of : landing-wba-dev, *
[2023-09-12, 13:07:45 UTC] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 'google_cloud_default' for task execution.
[2023-09-12, 13:07:45 UTC] {credentials_provider.py:354} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no explicit credentials are provided.
[2023-09-12, 13:08:45 UTC] {gcs.py:93} INFO - Sensor checks existence of : landing-wba-dev, *
```

Where the last 3 lines, is on repeated until timeout.

I can provide more context if required.

I have tried playing with the variables used for the DAG and sensor. None yielded any different results. I am hoping to see that the dummy process is triggered.

Thank you if you take the time to read or help assist.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `GoogleCloudStorageObjectSensor` doesn't support wildcard.

If you don't know the name of the object that is supposed to appear in GCS bucket you can use the next workaround to replace `GoogleCloudStorageObjectSensor`

```
def more_than_one_objects(gcs_objects, **kwargs):
    return len(gcs_objects) > 0


GoogleCloudStorageListOperator(
    task_id="list_gcs_objects",
    bucket=BUCKET_TO_MONITOR,
    prefix='' 
) >> PythonSensor(
    task_id='wait_for_any_object_appears',
    python_callable=more_than_one_objects
    op_kwargs={"gcs_objects": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(tasks_id=list_gcs_objects) }}"}
)
```